# Predict function and number of trees

Tags: r, random-forest

When using the predict function with a random forest regression model, do i still need to use an odd number of trees to ensure repeatable results? I understand that to be the case when there are ties for classification models, but not sure how it applies with regressions?

Answer (score 3):

No, we just need to set the random seed so each base-learner (tree) is trained on the same subset of dataset. Training an odd or an even number of base-learners has no relation to the repeatability of the results. The prediction is purely deterministic.